# Image URL to UIImage Not Working

Tags: ios, swift, url, firebase, uiimage

```
let url = URL(string: (pinsFIREBASE[marker.snippet!]?.imageURL)!)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
        self.postImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
}

task.resume()
```

I have the following code that takes a url from firebase, in the form https://i.stack.imgur.com/6edcX.jpg, and is supposed to turn that url into a UIImage that can be placed on a view. However, while extracting the text from the firebase object works, parsing the image URL doesn't seem to be working as I get an empty view. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of ignoring `error`, print it if `data` is `nil`. And all of those uses of `!` are bad.

Comment: Data is not nil. However, I did try to hard code links instead of getting them from the Pin object. For some reason, some links (the one I included above) work when hard-coded in but others don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know why, your code works. The problem is your image link. Your imageURL's HTTP type. iOS don't like HTTP type request because it's not safe.

- Plan A: Try a HTTPS type image link, it works.
- Plan B: Add "App Transport Security Settings" in project info ,and set "Allow
  Arbitrary Loads" yes in "App Transport Security Settings" dictionary.

I suggested use Plan A, that's Apple want iOSDev to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the () from after DispatchQueue.main.async(). Try this:

```
  let url = URL(string: (pinsFIREBASE[marker.snippet!]?.imageURL)!)
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
  guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.postImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
   }
 }

task.resume()
```

Comment: then it's something with your URL. I just tested (Xcode 8.2 and swift 3.1) in a blank Xcode project and it works. URL can not be HTTP, must be https.

Comment: Yeah, that's what ended up being the problem. Thanks!